# how to set an external link over a lightbox image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, lightbox

I have a gallery, and a admin gallery pages.

On the admin gallery i have a delete button appears over the image, but when i click on it, it is opening a lightbox load, instead of the message "Are you sure?".

I assume it is the code for the lightbox that is making the link do that.
How could i solve this?

```
<div class="lightbox-grid square-thumbs" data-gallery-title="Gallery">
    <ul>
       <% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
       <% gallery.pictures.each do |f| %>
         <div class="contentdeletar">
            <li>
              <div class="deletar">
                <%= link_to 'delete', f, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
               </div>
               <a href="<%= f.image.url(:large) %>" data-lightbox="true" data-title="<%= f.description %>">
               <div class="background-image-holder">
                  <img alt="image" class="background-image" src="<%= f.image.url(:large) %>">
               </div>
               </a>
            </li>
          </div>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The line `<%= link_to 'delete', f, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>` is not working for some reason.
I think that it tries to open the link inside the lightbox or something like that

Comment: Not sure what this code really does, by a first watch it seems to me that the markup is a bit strange because the gallery image stay inside a div called "contentdeletar" that probably aim to style the delete button. I would try to move the link `<a href="<%= f.image.url(:large) %>"...` and the div `<div class="background-image-holder">` tags after the end of the "contentdeletar" div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the `scripts.js` had this

```
$('.lightbox-grid li a').each(function(){
        var galleryTitle = $(this).closest('.lightbox-grid').attr('data-gallery-title');
        $(this).attr('data-lightbox', galleryTitle);
    });
```

So everithing as `a` would behave like that.

So I created a div named `dav` and put the lightbox link inside

```
<div class="deletar">
   <%= link_to 'delete', f, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</div>
<div class="dav">
   <a href="<%= f.image.url(:large) %>" data-lightbox="true" data-title="<%= f.description %>">
   <div class="background-image-holder">
      <img alt="image" class="background-image" src="<%= f.image.url(:large) %>">
   </div>
</div>
```

and updated the js file to `$('.lightbox-grid li dav a').each(function(){`
So now it will only work inside the `li dav a` links